# Mootools Highcharts radio button toggle between charts, working jQuery version

Tags: highcharts, mootools

I've created a Highcharts implementation with a working jQuery-based radio button toggle "view select" between two charts: http://jsfiddle.net/6sAYF/ (it's in the lower-right)

here is the working jQuery function and corresponding html:

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#0829-"+$(this).val()).fadeIn('fast');
    });
 });

<div id="0829-1" class="toHide" ></div>
<div id="0829-2" class="toHide" style="display:none;width:780px;"></div>

<label><input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" checked/>&#37;</label>
<label><input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" />2</label>
```

Where to start? Should I rewrite the function for Mootools? Use jQuery noconflict() mode and the original function?

My mootools version is here without toggle function: http://jsfiddle.net/JhWe6/

Many thanks to anyone with insight.

Comment: Just looked fast to your code, a bit late here. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/JhWe6/1/

Comment: are you seriously debating bringing in jquery vs rewriting TWO lines of the easiest DOM manipulation code ever? `.click(fn)` -> `.addEvent('click', fn)`, `$('selector')` -> `$$('')`, `$('#id')` -> `$('id')`, `.val()` -> `.get('value')`, `.fadeIn('fast')` -> `.fade('in')`

Comment: OK, so bringing in jQuery is a bad option. Thanks guys, still not working though. Based on your fiddle edit and Dimitars port help, I'm coming up with this, but it's still not working like the jQuery version:
`document.getElement("[name=toggler]").addEvent('click', function(){
            $$('.toHide').hide();
            $("0829-"+this.get('value')).fade('in');
    });`
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JhWe6/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/JhWe6/6/ - so basically the `.hide()` is in mootools-more so can't use that. also, the jquery fadeIn will check display property and make it visible before doing it, whereas a fade in mootools won't (the `.show()` will.). fixed it to use a manual display flick. however, this is a highcharts anti-pattern. you should use the series API and just swap data on the same chart instance, not swap two charts, where possible.

Comment: You can also use [standalone-framework](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/58-highcharts-standalone-framework) and get rid of one of your framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="graphwrap" style="height: 410px;">

<div id="divID-1" class="toHide" style="position:relative;margin-bottom:-400px;"></div>
<div id="divID-2" class="toHide" style="position:relative;top:-9999em;opacity:0;"></div>

<div id="viewSelectWrap">
<h4>View Select</h4>
<label><input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" style="cursor:pointer;" checked/>&#37;</label>
<label><input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" style="cursor:pointer;" />2</label>
</div>

</div>


window.addEvent('domready', function() {
document.getElements("[name=toggler]").addEvent('click', function(){
    $$('.toHide').setStyle('top', '-9999em');
    $$('.toHide').setStyle('opacity', '0');
    $("divID-"+this.get('value')).setStyle('top', '0').fade(0,1);
});  
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
         renderTo: 'divID-1',
         height: 400, //works with the margin-bottom style
         ...

var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
         renderTo: 'divID-2',
         height: 400,
         ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JhWe6/10/

Per Highcharts support, the correct way for Highcharts to be hidden on a page is to use CSS style="position:relative; top:-9999em;" and update the CSS "top" in my case MooTools' setStyle('top', '0'). I also added $$('.toHide').setStyle('opacity', '0'); which makes the fade in nice.

You'll also notice that I needed to margin-bottom:-400px my first div. Is that the correct way to compensate for the now-rendered-as-blank bottom div?