# Highcharts radio button toggle between charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, toggle

I'm trying to use radio buttons to toggle the display between two Highchart charts (different data series) using divs. I essentially need the accepted solution here: [Mootools Highcharts radio button toggle between charts, working jQuery version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817700/mootools-highcharts-radio-button-toggle-between-charts-working-jquery-version/24125548#24125548)
...but I can't work out how to specify the variables for each chart from my existing code. The above solution uses this format:

```
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
         renderTo: 'divID-1',
         height: 400,
         ...

var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
         renderTo: 'divID-2',
         height: 400,
         ...
```

whereas each of my charts are specified in the following format, e.g. Chart 1:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        decimalPoint: '.',
        thousandsSep: ','
    }
});

$.get('data_stackedarea_value.csv', function(csv) {
$('#divID-1').highcharts({

chart: {type: 'area'},
data: {csv: csv},
...
```

How can I translate these into variables that can be called by the initial toggle function?

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    document.getElements("[name=toggler]").addEvent('click', function(){
        $$('.toHide').setStyle('top', '-9999em');
        $$('.toHide').setStyle('opacity', '0');
        $("divID-"+this.get('value')).setStyle('top', '0').fade(0,1);
    });
```

Many thanks

Comment: it doesn't look like you've examined the fiddle or tried it. "toggler" is just the name of the label associated with the radio buttons (that have the % sign and the 2 at the bottom) .. Which radio button is selected triggers the toggle, it doesn't depend on your chart data. Btw, actually posting your own chart data or a fiddle of said data would help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example where I adopted the solution from [23817700](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817700) to use the way you are passing variables to the charts.

I couldn't resist also adapting the toggle code to use jQuery, since it was required already. You can try this is action in this fiddle provided by @RachelGallen: https://jsfiddle.net/ezc7oghm/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div id="graphwrap" style="height: 410px;">
            <div id="divID-1" class="toHide" style="position:relative;margin-bottom:-400px;"></div>
            <div id="divID-2" class="toHide" style="position:relative;top:-9999em;opacity:0;"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="viewSelectWrap">
            <h4>View Select</h4>
            <label><input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="divID-1" style="cursor:pointer;" checked/>1</label>
            <label><input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="divID-2" style="cursor:pointer;" />2</label>
        </div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('[name=toggler]').click(function () {
        $('.toHide').css({
            top: '-9999em',
            opacity: 0
        });
        var chartToShow = $(this).val();
        $('#' + chartToShow).css({
            top: 0,
            opacity: 1
        });
    });

    $('#divID-1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
    $('#divID-2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Time spent on hobbies'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Skiing', 'Bicycling', 'Swimming']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Time spent on hobbies'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks. After loading highcharts over https it seemed to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ezc7oghm/1/

Comment: @Bemmu Great, thank you. How can I set the <div id="graphwrap"> height to a relative value (e.g. 100%) (currently "height: 410px") and still correctly stack the two child divs <divID-1> and <divID-2> on top of each other? This seems to rely on divID-1 using margin-bottom:-400px. Ideally this wouldn't be a fixed value.

Comment: For each child div set style="position:absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;vertical-align:top;"